# Struggling to see the utility of custom Django Model Managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I do not have any code for this question, so this will be more about the utility of customer Managers, more so than it is an implementation question.

I have read the documentation, many blog posts and tried to implement some myself, but I cannot find the utility in Django custom model Managers. I understand that they can help segment code and can help with DRY principles, but I struggle to see how. So this question can be broken down into a few subpoints

- How does this help with DRY principles?
- How does this help with code segmentation?
- What can managers do that `views` or `model` methods cannot do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate filtering, annotating, subqueries, etc. in a manager. For example:

```
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            active=True
        )
```

and then apply this to a module with an `active` field:

```
class MyActiveModel(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ActiveManager()
```

Now if we use `MyActiveModel.objects.all()`, it will only retrieve records with `active = True`. We thus do not need to apply this filtering in all views, we can make use of `objects` like in any model, and it will transparently filter the object.

A `Manager` is also often used if you want to make an extension on the queryset.

For example we can define an `AuthorQuerySet`, that offers an extra method `.of_user(…)` that for example retains the records where the given user is the author, or the user is a super user, retrieve all records with:

```
class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def from_user(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return self
        else:
            return self.filter(author=user)
```

and then work with a manager that allows one to do this filtering:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    objects = AuthorQuerySet.as_manager()
```

then we can retrieve objects that a user can see with:

```
Post.objects.filter_user(myuser)
```

or do this in a chain of filters:

```
Post.objects.filter(title__istartswith='The').filter_user(myuser)
```

It thus mainly deals with encapsulating logic, such that the filtering, annotating, etc. is defined only once and then used in the views in a *transparent* way. In other words, the view does not need to worry that it will retrieve only active objects, the manager takes care of that.

> How does this help with code segmentation?

A model focusses on storing a record in the database and to present data. Normally it should *not* decide what records you see in what situation. The *views* are used for that. But if the logic is the same, it makes no sense to write this in the views, since it makes the code error prone in case the filtering, annotation, etc. that (nearly) always should happen, is in that case copied to a large number of views. By implementing this in the manager, we have a layer between the models and the views that can filter, annotate, etc. data always in the same way.

> What can managers do that views or model methods cannot do?

One can repeat the same filtering code once per view, but that makes it hard to change that logic later on in the process, since then one should look in which views these models are accessed, and make changes to *all* these views. This would make it easy to overlook something and thus end up with an inconsistent state.

One can also define static methods in the models to do the filtering. But the same model can work with *multiple* managers, such that, depending on the case, another model is selected.

It is in other words a layer between the model and the view, and it works in a many-to-one to the model and a many-to-many to the view code.

Comment: Just to confirm, this line of code `Post.objects.filter_user(myuser)` would theoretically replace something like `Post.objects.filter(author=username)`?

My other question is - isn't this a bit restrictive? I understand you can have multiple managers with different names, so could you do something like

`object_author = AuthorObjectFilter()` or something along those lines, and then `objects=defaultusermanager`?

Comment: @jeremy_lord: yes, although in this answer we first check the user and filter only if it is not a superuser, so you can encapsulate more complex logic in a manager, and then reuse the same logic in multiple views. This might be useful if you think later it might change (for example that besides the superuser or the author, the manager of the author can see this too). You thus define logic once, and reuse it in the views.

Comment: Thanks for being so quick with your response! You were so quick that I think you might have missed an edit that I made haha
It'd be great if you could review the latter part of my comment, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to briefly answer on your question leaving a room of deeper answers for another commenters. Also no code.

> How does this help with DRY principles?

Usually, and specially in larger projects, you'll have a set of queries that are (re)used widely over the code. For example, getting a shopping list for a user or fetching some account meta-data with annotated fields. In case of keeping these queries in custom model manager you can:

- define them in single place and re-use in any other
- modify their functionality in single place without the need of keeping care about searching & modifying places where you actually use manager method (query)

Basically, following this principle (with custom managers, in your case) you reduce the complexity of the code base you need to operate with.

> How does this help with code segmentation?

All your query-related stuff lives in manager of appropriate model - you don't mess representation and business logic along with some utility things all over the code-base. Manager method don't know anything about their consumers and consumers don't need to know anything about those methods implementation.

> What can managers do that views or model methods cannot do?

With managers you can change returned queryset and that will be a default change for every consumer. Also, speaking about managers vs models, there's a semantic difference: methods of the model assumed to operate specifically over data kept by model instance or something relative to any model instance, where managers operate over any non-specific entities (yet of same model). Think of this like "model methods do something over table row and managers do something over table rows".

Comment: This definitely helped with my understanding of managers and semantics in general, so thank you for that. I will wait for a few more answers and then accept one as the answer